# Does calling ob_end_clean() once at the top of a script guarantee ob_flush() is never needed?

Tags: php

When using PHP as the back-end for SSE (Server Sent Events) and similar server streaming solutions, I have been using the `@ob_flush();@flush()` idiom to make sure the data gets spat out immediately.  (The ordering is important: `ob_flush()` flushes PHP's buffers, `flush()` then tells Apache to flush it too.)

I started thinking about it after reading that `@` is slow. (In fact, according to comments in the PHP manual it adds roughly 0.005ms, so I've reclassified "slow" as "don't worry about it unless inside a tight loop"). I need the `@` on `ob_flush()` to stop it complaining when the output buffer is empty. BTW, I've followed through the source code until it reached Apache and it appears `flush()` does not throw any PHP errors.

Now I'm wondering if I can reduce the above `@ob_flush();@flush()` to just `@flush()` (or even just `flush()`)? Again in PHP manual comments I find someone saying you could do this at the top of your script: `if (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();`  (Which can be abbreviated to simply `@ob_end_clean();`)

My question is: Is that a reliable command to mean output buffering will never be used and `ob_flush()` will never be needed? Across all PHP versions (well at least php 5.2 onwards) and all supported operating systems, with whatever weird settings a user might have put in php.ini?

(If your answer is "no", please describe under which situations `ob_flush()` could still be needed.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php

```
//at start of script...
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
```

returns unbuffered output

Side Note: You shouldn't be displaying php errors to the screen in a production environment, so you shouldn't have any need to use the @ error suppressor.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The comments make it sound like that function is unreliable (the comments are very old though, so hard to be sure). The comments on the ob_end_flush manual entry are also interesting. (This doesn't really answer my question; in fact the opposite, as now I have more questions, and it makes me think the answer might be "no". E.g. one of the comments mentioned how PHP sessions force ob functions on?)

Comment: Re: displaying php errors. With SSE, any extra output to stdout messes everything up. But, thinking about it now, maybe forcing error logging, even in development, for SSE scripts, is better than using @.