# Howto make Apache stop buffering POST data?

Tags: php, apache

When uploading a file via XHR streaming to a PHP script running on an Apache webserver, something is buffering the entire POST body and then handing it off to PHP once the entire file has been uploaded.

This is very memory intensive and not optimal. I have another server configured roughly the same way which streams the POST data directly to the PHP script resulting in low memory usage.

I can't for the life of me figure out the configuration difference. Is there anything obvious like a setting "BufferPostBody Yes" that I should look for?

**What I've tried so far**

Disabling mod_security
  Sending file through HTTP and not HTTPs
  Checking apache logs, php logs, syslogs. No errors or warnings present.

**How I'm testing the behavior**

Begin upload via JS of large file(235M) via XHR streaming. PHP should output 'performing upload' as soon as the request starts. Instead the line 'performing upload' is seen only after the entire file is uploaded via POST.

The list of loaded modules on the bad server is:

core
mod_log_config
mod_logio
prefork
http_core
mod_so
mod_alias
mod_auth_basic
mod_authn_file
mod_authz_default
mod_authz_groupfile
mod_authz_host
mod_authz_user
mod_autoindex
mod_cgi
mod_dir
mod_env
mod_mime
mod_negotiation
mod_php5
mod_reqtimeout
mod_rewrite
mod_setenvif
mod_ssl
mod_status
mod_unique_id

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650187/does-calling-ob-end-clean-once-at-the-top-of-a-script-guarantee-ob-flush-is/18652249#18652249

Comment: This is not a dup. My question involves INPUT, not output buffering. The problem is not with PHP waiting to provide script output but with Apache providing input to the PHP script.

Comment: It's perhaps not apache that "caches" the POST input data, but PHP that wants to process it all *before* your script starts. I've not tested it but I've seen is the [`enable_post_data_reading` ini setting](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.enable-post-data-reading), PHP then will not fill `$_POST` and `$_FILES` and you need to process the POST-data on your own.

Comment: Using `PUT` will roughly accomplish what you want here; PHP can just pull from `php://input`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the PHP setting `enable_post_data_reading` to `Off`. I have found this to be the cause of the request buffering by PHP, and thus not allowing the stream to work like a stream.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading

This disables both `$_POST` and `$_FILES` variables so, if you are using them in the rest of your app, it could be a problem.

To get around that I have an Apache configuration that only enables it under certain conditions.

In this case, a Location and Content Type:

```
<Location /uri/to/path/file.php>
    <If "req('Content-Type') = 'application/customfiletype'">
        php_value enable_post_data_reading Off
    </If>
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP assumes that the entire POST request is available, so waiting for the post to finish before starting PHP is per design, I believe. And probably unavoidable.

What you can do is split the file with the HTML5 file API in the browser, and then send the file chunks one by one, each in its own PHP POST request.

An example of how to split a file in the browser with HTML5: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Browser support for the HTML5 file API: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi (doesn't work in fx IE<10 :( )